# Jquery .each Function

Tags: jquery

I want to get the properties through `.each` function?

```
public class UserDto
{
  public List<UserNode> UserList { get; set; } 
}

public class UserNode
    {
        public UserNode()
        {
            UserViews = new List<string>();
        }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public IList<string> UserViews { get; set; }
    }
```

how i can extract values through .each function? i wanna to show the id and userviews?

```
success: function (userDetails) {

          $.each(userDetails, function() {
                  $.each(this, function (key, value) {

                                alert(value);


                       });​

                       });​

                },
```

any way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You were close.  Just stop here:

```
$.each(userDetails, function() {
```

but add parameters

```
$.each(userDetails, function(key, value) {
```

inside of the callback you'll have access to each property name in the object, as well its corresponding value.

```
$.each(userDetails, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value, userDetails[key], userDetails[key] === value);
});
```

Here's a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkZaC/)**

Comment: Id,UserViews  need to extract.bz of this i used .each twice? any idea?there may be several id's and views need to display

Comment: @user2537795 - if one of the values you're iterating over is an object, and you want to iterate over *that*, then you'd make a second call to `$.each` - ie, `if (key === 'foo'){ $.each(value, function(key2, value2){ /// }) ... `

Comment: i tried this and it;s not giving wht i expected. $.each(userDetails.UserList, function() {
                            $.each(this, function (key, value) {

                                alert(value);
                               
                                
                        });​

                        });​

Comment: @user2537795 - have you debugged?  Have you placed a debugger breakpoint inside of the outer `each` callback to inspect each value?

Comment: yep,i added alert and check the values. $.each(userDetails.UserList, function() { $.each(this, function (key, value) { alert(value); });​ }); this one giving close answer.but not perfect one

Comment: You need to add debugger statements, and actually step into the code, and look at the actual objects you're working with.  There's not much to uUsing $.each - you're just not getting quite the data structure you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
for(var a in model)          
{

  var model2=model[a].UserViews;
    for (var k in model2) 
     {
        alert(model2[k]);

      }

}
```